# Auto resizing tableview cell with its detailTextLabel?

Tags: swift, uikit

Is here anyway to use native cell and resize to detailTextLabel size ?

Cell configuration:

```
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: UITableViewCell.reuseID)
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
```

In my case textLabel have only 1 line, but detailTextLabel got 3.
[image]

I noticed by adding some "\n" on textLabel.text, cell would finally resize correctly,
any cleaner solution ?

Comment: Is textLabel the Label on the left side of the cell? (eg Birth Date and Address) and the detailTextLabel the label for the actual information you want to display? (15/10/1995 and 1, 2, 3)

Comment: @Banane42 Yes, actually i want it resize upon detailTextLabel, wondering if there is anyway without making an custom class.

Comment: If you want to customize the height for specific rows you can look at the [TableViewDelegate heightForRowAt](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview)

Answer (score 1):

1. Set up top and bottom constraints of the label with the cell.
2. Set the label number of rows to 0.
3. Set automatic dimension and estimated row height to table view.

   ```
   self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50 
   self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
   ```